# Why is my callback function never being called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-oauth

Im trying to do a login authentication in react js using GoogleOAuth API. In my App im able to log in to different authorized google users but in one part of my code i sen a callback function but it is never being executed.

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';
import LoginBtn from './components/atoms/LoginBtn';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';


function App() {
  const [ user, setUser ] = useState({}) //Store my user data


  function handleCallbackResponse(response){
    var userData = jwt_decode(response.credentials);
    console.log(userData);
    setUser(userData);
  }

  
  useEffect(() => {
    /*global google*/
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: "Google Cliente goes here",
      callback: handleCallbackResponse
    });

  }, []); //useEffect will run only if anything inside the empty array  
  
  
  return (

    <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId="My Google client goes here">
      <div className="App">
        <LoginBtn />
      </div>
    </GoogleOAuthProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So above i pasted my App component with its logic so that you can follow completely.
The following is the function not being executed

For any reasons this is never console.loging anything in my console:

```
function handleCallbackResponse(response){
    var userData = jwt_decode(response.credentials);
    console.log(userData);
    setUser(userData);
  }
```

The function above is called in the following code of block:

```
useEffect(() => {
    /*global google*/
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: "Google Cliente goes here",
      callback: handleCallbackResponse
    });

  }, []); //useEffect will run only if anything inside the empty array
```

At my index.html i pasted the following script to access global google keywords and js objects.
Which is between my head tags.

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of google.accounts.id , use window.google.accounts.id

```
window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
client_id: CLIENT_ID,
callback: data => handleCredentialResponse(data),
state_cookie_domain: 'https://example.com',});
```

Comment: Same issue not getting there, the prompt is shwoing up in the console, but the block of code that calls the callback function is never being called.  Im getting a token when i loggin and after a few seconds i get a 401 unauthorized error. @Jason